# Meaning of the terms "operation" and "invariant" in the old group theory paper

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

I am reading an old paper *C.Hopkins, "Non-abelian groups whose groups of isomorphisms are abelian", 1928.(Link: [1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968020))* I don't know what the term "**operation**" and "**invariant**" mean. The example phrases include:

1. A necessary and sufficient condition that an **operation** of the group of isomorphisms of an abelian group be **invariant** under this group is that it should transform every **operation** of this abelian group into the same power of itself.
2. Since the central quotient group of *G* is simply isomorphic
   with the group of inner isomorphisms of *G*, it is clear that every commutator
   of *G* is **invariant** under *G*.
3. The symbol *G* shall consistently denote a non-abelian group whose group of isomorphisms *I* is abelian; **operations** in *G* and **operations** of I shall be denoted by lower- case and capital letters respectively; an isomorphism of *G* with itself will often be called an automorphism.

Does the "operation" means a group action or an element of the group? Also, what does  "invariant under the group *G*" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Operation" here means "element"; groups used to be thought of as collections of "operations on sets" (even after Cayley; this is the language used in Burnside's book, for example). So "operations of $G$" means "elements of $G$" and "operations of $I$" means "elements of $I$" (which here are automorphisms of $G$).

"Invariant subgroup" is an old term for "normal subgroup." So "invariant under this group" means that the element is fixed under conjugation; i.e., that it is central.

So what you quote would be expressed today perhaps as follows:

> 1. A necessary and sufficient condition for an element $f$ of $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$, $A$ abelian, be central is that for all $a\in A$, $f(a)=a^k$ for some $k$.
> 2. Since the central quotient of a group $G$, $G/Z(G)$, is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$, every commutator of $G$ is central in $G$.
> 3. $G$ will denote a non-abelian group such that $I=\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is abelian. Elements of $G$ and of $I$ will be represented by lower case letters. An isomorphism of $G$ with itself is called an automorphism.

Do these make sense? I think so. It is easy to verify that automorphisms of an abelian group of the form $a\mapsto a^k$ (for fixed $k$) are central in $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$. The converse is, I believe, true but a bit trickier; I believe that for finite abelian groups it is the analog of the fact that the center of $\mathsf{GL}_n(F)$ consists of the scalar multiples of the identity...

For 2, since $G/Z(G)$ embeds into $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, if $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is abelian, then $G/Z(G)$ is abelian, and therefore $[G,G]\subseteq Z(G)$.

3 is just notation.

Comment: Thank you! Now it becomes clear. May I ask you another question? Does the term "holomorph of G" means the semidirect product of G and Aut(G)? Although it is true now, I think Hol(G) may have been used with a different meaning at the time this paper was written. The example phrase include:
"We shall now prove that every commutator of G is a characteristic operation: i.e. an invariant operation under the holomorph of G"

Comment: Also, I have no idea how the elements in Aut(G) and the elements in G can be multiplied, for example, S^{-1} t S = t c where S is in Aut(G) and t, c are in G. I don't think this is an evaluation of S or S^{-1} at t.

Comment: @aleph0 I don't have access to the paper, so I can't check. In the semidirect product $G\rtimes\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, you multiply them like you do in any semidirect product. The action of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ on $G$ is by evaluation. Whether you are defining a left or right action depends on how you define the semidirect product. But I am not going to "translate" the whole paper for you into modern notation/nomenclature. If you are unable to puzzle your way through it, then perhaps you aren't ready to read it.